# Polymer callback as an attribute

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Not so long ago I noticed that iron-ajax uses an attribut `on-response="callbackFn"` to execute once a response is received.

My question is simply how does this work?

I have a similar situation where I would like create a component that is able to take a callback as an attribute but I can't figure out how to do it.

Two things I noticed

1. When triggered the function is correctly bound to the Polymer element from which it came.
2. "callbackFn" is the name of a function.  Not a polymer binding.

So I assumed iron-ajax must be doing some trickery in the background to bind the given function referenced by function name.  When I looked at the source code though I don't see any handling of the 'on-response' attribute. none, zilch, nada.  what gives?

I can see that there is a `_boundedHandleResponse` but that property does not seem to be bound to the `on-response` function at any point.

[source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/master/iron-ajax.html#L466)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_boundedHandleResponse` is a function which is value depends upon the `_handleResponse` function.

```
_boundHandleResponse: {
  type: Function,
  value: function () {
    return this._handleResponse.bind(this);
  }
}
```

So, if you check the `_handleResponse` function there is a 'response' event which is dispatched using the code :

```
this.fire('response', request, {
  bubbles: this.bubbles,
  composed: true
});
```

In polymer element we add event listeners using on-*event* annotations. For example on-tap, on-click. So, every time `response` is dispatched it will call the function defined as on `on-response="callbackFn"` which will call the "callbackFn" function.